# Adding axis data to highchart

Tags: asp.net, highcharts

i am using highcharts to plot graph along x and y axis using following code.

```
        DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart");
        chart.SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Segment Pressure Points" });
        chart.SetXAxis(new XAxis { Title = new XAxisTitle { Text = "Kilometers" }, Min = 0, MinRange = 14 * 20 });
        chart.SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "db" }, Min = 0, MinRange = 0.6 * 1 });
        chart.SetSeries(new Series { Name = "Fiber No:1",Data=new Data(new     object[]{20,50,89,158,190}),YAxis="0"});
```

I want to add points on given values of x and y axis on the graph, currently i am using above setseries method but it is only ploting points against y-axis not x-axis. How can i plot points having both axis values?

Comment: Try to replcate your each point by object, including x/y value, I mean that each point should be in that form: {x:3 ,y: 20} etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
chart.setSeries(new Series {Name = "Fiber No:1", Data new Data(new Object[]{{x:0, y:20},{x:2, y:50},{x:7, y:89},{x:9, y:158},{x:10, y:190},})}), yAxis = 0});
```

you can follow any sequence of x values,

if you go with an ascending order of x values then you will a smooth chart
there can be gaps (this type of data will result in irregular interval chart while the data given by you results in regular interval charts).

Comment: do you have any example tried out in JSfiddle or code pen. you can share it with us. it will  be useful

Comment: solved was just missing this                                                                       new Series { Name = "Fiber No:24", Data = new Data(new object[,] { { 0, 0 }, { segment_length.Text, 0 } }) }